# Select array element out of bounds on purpose

Tags: arrays, lua

Assume the following array:

```
a = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

Using `a[3]`, I can access `c`. But how do I make the string "repeat forever" (while it still only has elements)? Example:

```
a[4] --will return nil, but I need to to return "a", because 4 is 3 (end of array) + 1 (the element I need).
```

**Question:**

How would I make `a[4]` return the same value as `a[1]`, if `a[]` consists of 3 elements?

Comment: BTW—A table is not an array. A table may contain a sequence or not. Your "consists of 3 elements" seems to be an example of a [sequence length](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7). As long as your table contains a sequence, the algorithms using `#t` will work. You can add keys that aren't positive integers, too. When adding or removing positive integer keys, don't break the sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either make sure that the key you use is within proper range or you move that logic into a's metatable by implementing the `__index` metamethod. That way you tell Lua what to return when someone accesses an invalid key in your table.
See http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetamethodsTutorial

```
local function circle(arr)
   setmetatable(arr, {__index =
      function(t, k)
         if type(k) == "number" and #t > 0 then
            return rawget(t, (k-1) % #t + 1)
         end
      end
   })
end

local a = {"a", "b", "c"}
circle(a)

for j = -10, 10 do
   print(j, a[j])
end
```

Comment: @Piglet - Probably, you should exercise your typing speed :-)

Comment: This works well, and is also valid if `j` is a literal number. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a slight variation of Egor Skriptunoff's correct answer because I didn't want the formatting to be lost if left as comment.

In my view, this one makes the table creation a simpler single statement, and clearer as to the intended action.  It also uses the same table as meta-table as a minor optimization.

```
local
function circle(arr)
  function arr.__index(t, k)
    if type(k) == 'number' and #t > 0 then
      return rawget(t, (k-1) % #t + 1)
    end
  end
  return setmetatable(arr,arr)
end

local a = circle {'a', 'b', 'c'}

for j = -10, 10 do print(j, a[j]) end
```